# Extra space appears when using :before selector

Tags: css

I'm not a CSS specialist. I have a DRUPAL site, using a theme based on bootstrap. I use the bootstrap alert boxes in order to display important messages on the homepage. It works well, except that I get extra space when adding some content in a :before selector. I created a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wzLzmjen/1/)

Is there a simple way to solve this extra space? I solved the issue by setting line-height to 0 to the ancestor of the alert, but then when reducing the page, text doesn't go to new line and gets imbricated with itself.
Thanks for help.

Here is the code:

```css
#top-content .block .views-row::before {
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: #f37021;
  content: "\e101";
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-size: 2em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  left: 0.35em;
  /*line-height: 1;*/
  position: relative;
  top: 0.3em;
}
/*#top-content .block .views-row {
 padding-bottom:1.2em;
}*/

#top-content .block .views-row .views-field {
  margin-left: 3em;
}
#top-content .block a {
  color: #f37021;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="top-content">
  <div class="container clearfix">
    <div class="clearfix" id="top-content-inside">
      <div class="region region-highlighted">
        <div class="block block-views contextual-links-region clearfix" id="block-views-alerts-block-1">

          <div class="contextual-links-wrapper contextual-links-processed"><a href="#" class="contextual-links-trigger">Configure</a>
            <ul class="contextual-links">
              <li class="views-ui-edit first"><a href="/en/admin/structure/views/view/alerts/edit/block_1?destination=node/385">Edit view</a>
              </li>
              <li class="block-configure last"><a href="/en/admin/structure/block/manage/views/alerts-block_1/configure?destination=node/385">Configure</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            <div class="view view-alerts view-id-alerts view-display-id-block_1 view-dom-id-281661d0f4b7c5128ce6ef7abc38dfb1">
              <div class="view-content">
                <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first alert alert-info fade in">
                  <div class="views-field views-field-nothing"> <span class="field-content"><a aria-label="close" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" href="#">×</a></span> 
                  </div>
                  <div class="views-field views-field-title"> <span class="field-content"><a href="/nl/content/wiv-isp-closed-between-1st-and-5th-november">WIV-ISP closed between 1st and 5th of November</a></span> 
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even views-row-last alert alert-info fade in">
                  <div class="views-field views-field-nothing"> <span class="field-content"><a aria-label="close" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" href="#">×</a></span> 
                  </div>
                  <div class="views-field views-field-title"> <span class="field-content"><a href="/nl/content/treinramp-wetteren">Treinramp in Wetteren</a></span> 
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where should the icon be positioned? Left of the text, or above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `float:left` and remove `top:0.3em`

```
#top-content .block .views-row::before {
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    color: #f37021;
    content: "\e101";
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 2em;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    left: 0.35em;
    line-height: 1; //uncommented this
    float:left; //added this
    position: relative;
    /*top:0.3em*/ //removed this

}
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wzLzmjen/3/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. float-left is indeed the best way to achieve this. Icon and text are now perfectly aligned.

Comment: I am glad this helped you Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is positioned to the left of your content.
It looks like you were targeting the wrong div with your before. I also added a left to give it a bit of space. see the result below

Changed the target div from:

```
#top-content .block .views-row::before
```

to:

```
.views-field-title .field-content:before
```

Updated the left to:

```
left: -10px;
```

The results are below:

```css
.views-field-title .field-content:before {
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    color: #f37021;
    content: "\e101";
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 2em;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    /*line-height: 1;*/
    position: relative;
    top: 0.3em;
left:-10px;
}
/*#top-content .block .views-row {
 padding-bottom:1.2em;
}*/
#top-content .block .views-row .views-field{
 margin-left: 3em;
}
#top-content .block a {
    color: #f37021;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="top-content">
        <div class="container clearfix">

            
                            <div class="clearfix" id="top-content-inside">
                      <div class="region region-highlighted">
    <div class="block block-views contextual-links-region clearfix" id="block-views-alerts-block-1">

    <div class="contextual-links-wrapper contextual-links-processed"><a href="#" class="contextual-links-trigger">Configure</a><ul class="contextual-links"><li class="views-ui-edit first"><a href="/en/admin/structure/views/view/alerts/edit/block_1?destination=node/385">Edit view</a></li>
<li class="block-configure last"><a href="/en/admin/structure/block/manage/views/alerts-block_1/configure?destination=node/385">Configure</a></li>
</ul></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="view view-alerts view-id-alerts view-display-id-block_1 view-dom-id-281661d0f4b7c5128ce6ef7abc38dfb1">
        
  
  
      <div class="view-content">
        <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first alert alert-info fade in">
      
  <div class="views-field views-field-nothing">        <span class="field-content"><a aria-label="close" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" href="#">×</a></span>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-title">        <span class="field-content"><a href="/nl/content/wiv-isp-closed-between-1st-and-5th-november">WIV-ISP closed between 1st and 5th of November</a></span>  </div>  </div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even views-row-last alert alert-info fade in">
      
  <div class="views-field views-field-nothing">        <span class="field-content"><a aria-label="close" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" href="#">×</a></span>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-title">        <span class="field-content"><a href="/nl/content/treinramp-wetteren">Treinramp in Wetteren</a></span>  </div>  </div>
    </div>
  
  
  
  
  
  
</div>  </div>
</div>
  </div>
                </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you're applying 2 `left`s pseudo-class, thats not possible, since it will only use one of them.

Comment: One of them has been removed. the first left was being overridden with the second left anyway. You can edit the left or the top to position it the way that you want